# Block Apache HttpClient 4 from accessing a specific route

Tags: java, http, apache-httpclient-4.x

What is the easiest way to give HttpClient a list of routes, host names, IP addresses that should be prevented from access?

Something like this (this code doesn't work, you can't set 0 now):

```
HttpHost block = new HttpHost("example.com", 80);
cm.setMaxPerRoute(new HttpRoute(block), 0);
```

Comment: Block exactly how? Would throwing an exception be good enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
final Set<HttpHost> sitesToBlock = new HashSet<HttpHost>();
sitesToBlock.add(new HttpHost("example.com", 80));

DefaultRoutePlanner routePlanner = new DefaultRoutePlanner(DefaultSchemePortResolver.INSTANCE) {

    @Override
    public HttpRoute determineRoute(
            final HttpHost host, final HttpRequest request, final HttpContext context) throws HttpException {

        final HttpRoute route = super.determineRoute(host, request, context);
        if (sitesToBlock.contains(route.getTargetHost())) {
            throw new HttpException("Connection to " + host + " is blocked");
        }
        return route;
    }
};

CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.custom()
        .setRoutePlanner(routePlanner)
        .build();

}
```

Comment: nice solution, but why not simply use `sitesToBlock.contains(host)` rather than accessing the target host of the route?

Comment: The route planner among many things also resolves default ports: http://host:-1 -> http://host:80

Comment: @oleg it works perfectly for hostnames, thank you! Is there something similar to block an IP address?

Comment: @Shcheklein Custom DnsResolver would be another way of refusing connections based on IP of the opposite endpoint instead of the route. Please note though that one cannot differentiate proxied and direct connections when using DnsResolver. The complete route would not be available.